# On mac eclipse+android, src and layout folder is getting created empty, even HTTPS didnt work

Tags: android, macos, layout, src

Empty src and layout folder :

First of all, I read through other questions related to this, but still my problem is different. Even installing software with "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/", still it is same.

I tried the following as well...
1. Deleted entire eclipse and its workspace
2. Downloaded fresh eclipse with android SDK, and did use above said URL to install plugin

Still didnt work. Having Apple's latest Java updates as well. Anybody faced this issue? Apart from workspace deletion, new eclipse installation, and above said URL any other things should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got my problem solved with few R&Ds. As I said even after deleting the eclipse folder and workspace it didn't resolve my issue. But those are not complete removal of eclipse.

So I tried deleting every traces of eclipse in my mac and after that I've download freshly eclipse and followed other steps of SDK and ADT plugin, now it is happily working.

To remove completely eclipse from mac, follow these...
(one who doesn't know where to do this, go to finder, select GO menu and select Go to folder and enter this one by one)
    ~/Library/Saved Application and remove this "org.eclipse.eclipse.savedState
    ~/Library/Preferences and remove this "org.eclipse.eclipse.plist"
    ~/Library/Caches and remove this "org.eclipse.eclipse"

Also delete any org.eclipse... if it is additionally available in these paths. And this worked for me.